# How do you override sequential id allocation in a seed file?

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following seed file entry:

```
shapes = Shape.create([
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Rectangle',
    surface_count: 4,
    created_at: Time.now,
    updated_at: Time.now
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'H-shape',
    surface_count: 12,
    created_at: Time.now,
    updated_at: Time.now
  }
])
```

When I seed my SQLite database I end up with two rows that have ids one and two, not one and three.  This is just a sample.  The actual table is much larger.  I am trying to get my test environment to match my production environment where the second row was just deleted and the remaining rows were left as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite allows you to override an autoincrement simply by including the field in your insert statement.

From your description, it seems likely that your actual insert statement is not including `id` and your `id` is defined as `autoincrement`.  If you are using some kind of framework to serialize, you'll need to see how it is defined there and how it treats autoincrement fields.  Tracing the actual SQL statement should tell you.